# update if exists, insert if not

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to update a table in which if the data is already created I will only update it and if it does not exist it will not insert but when I try to save it gives me an error in the number of parameters. this is my code:

```
 $sql = "insert into detalle_Dproducto
        values(null,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
        on duplicate key update 
      numero_Dproducto=?,
      productoc=?,
      id_Mprima=?,
      materiales=?,
      unidadm=?,
      moneda=?,
      precio=?,
      cantidad=?,
      importe=?,
      id_usuario=?,
      id_producto=?,
      estado=?
      where
      id_detalle_Dproducto=?
      ";
      
    $sql = $conectar->prepare($sql);

    $sql->bindValue(1, $numero_Dproducto);
    $sql->bindValue(2, $productoc);
    $sql->bindValue(3, $id_Mprima);
    $sql->bindValue(4, $materiales);
    $sql->bindValue(5, $unidadm);
    $sql->bindValue(6, $moneda);
    $sql->bindValue(7, $precio);
    $sql->bindValue(8, $cantidad);
    $sql->bindValue(9, $importe);
    $sql->bindValue(10, $id_usuario);
    $sql->bindValue(11, $id_producto);
    $sql->bindValue(12, $estado);
    $sql->bindValue(13, $id_detalle_Dproducto);

      $sql->execute();
```

Comment: I'd always use prepared statement with named placeholders + Also don't overwrite your variable `$sql`, Define a new var instead e.g. `$statement = $conectar->prepare($sql);` instead of `$sql = $conectar->prepare($sql);` as `$sql` is actually a string in this case

Comment: tranks for the info

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $conectar->prepare("INSERT INTO detalle_Dproducto (id_detalle_Dproducto,numero_Dproducto,productoc,id_Mprima,materiales,unidadm,moneda,precio,cantidad,importe,fecha_Dproducto,id_usuario,id_producto,estado) 
    VALUES (:id_detalle_Dproducto,:numero_Dproducto,:productoc,:id_Mprima,:materiales,:unidadm,:moneda,:precio,:cantidad,:importe,:now(),:id_usuario,:id_producto,:estado)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  

numero_Dproducto=:numero_Dproducto,
productoc=:productoc,
id_Mprima=:id_Mprima,
materiales=:materiales,
unidadm=:unidadm,
moneda=:moneda,
precio=:precio,
cantidad=:cantidad,
importe=:importe,
id_usuario=:id_usuario,
id_producto=:id_producto,
estado=:estado");

$stmt->bindValue(':id_detalle_Dproducto', $id_detalle_Dproducto);
$stmt->bindValue(':numero_Dproducto', $numero_Dproducto);
$stmt->bindValue(':productoc', $productoc);
$stmt->bindValue(':id_Mprima', $id_Mprima);
$stmt->bindValue(':materiales', $materiales);
$stmt->bindValue(':unidadm', $unidadm);
$stmt->bindValue(':moneda', $moneda);
$stmt->bindValue(':precio', $precio);
$stmt->bindValue(':cantidad', $cantidad);
$stmt->bindValue(':importe', $importe);
$stmt->bindValue(':id_usuario', $id_usuario);
$stmt->bindValue(':id_producto', $id_producto);
$stmt->bindValue(':estado', $estado);



$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I have deleted my answer I thing first you have to understand working of `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/#:~:text=The%20INSERT%20ON%20DUPLICATE%20KEY,MySQL%20will%20issue%20an%20error.&text=If%20the%20existing%20row%20is%20updated%20using%20its%20current%20values,of%20affected%2Drows%20is%200.

Comment: In data base primary key and unique id flags are set or not?

Comment: and remove semi colon from value close bracket line end

Comment: ohh that was the problem thank you very much for all my friend

Comment: I leave the answer already modified for example

Comment: can I ask you one more question?

Comment: when I insert a data it does not add the number of the formula that the variable is numero_Dproducto